# Understanding the concept of highload application

Tags: load-balancing, high-load, architecture

So, I have an idea of creating highload app using Ruby on rails. However there are some questions about the conception of the project.

The main idea is

```
Client->Load Balancer -> Server_1 ->Database_1 (Master)
                      -> Server_2 ->Database_2 (Slave)
```

I've understand that the load balancer analyzes the traffic and send it to one of the servers. They call the database to retrieve data, but I want to include here

1. Statistic server that gazer the data on many layer.
2. API server that allows developers communicate with server.
3. Cache server

Concerning the first item, I think that I should put it behind load-balancer too and just send important data to it via the application. Am I right? But I don't know where I should put the API server, because it should operate separately. Is there in load-balancer some functionality that allow resend request to another server, like if the query `api.example.com/get/data/id/1` was asked, than send it to `server_3` where methods that execute this query are?

And the last one question is about the cache server. I'm not quite understand how for example azure web-balancer works? Can it solve this issue or I should add my own cache server? And where should it be placed?

P.S. I'm just read it and try to build approximate picture of my project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct, your statistics gathering server should live entirely behind the load balancer. Have it consume the data directly from the servers, whether it `tail`'s access logs, or you push data specifically to it, or whatever. It has nothing to do with the load balancer.
2. Can the API co-exist with the main application? If it can, just install the API on both `server_1` and `server_2`, on a different binding, and just let it load balance with everything else.

   If the API cannot co-exist on `server_1` or `server_2`, then put it on the same level as the other servers (say, `server-3`) and put a rule in your load balancer to send requests that match `api.example.com` to `server_3` only.
3. I'm not sure what you mean by cache server. A cache server could be something like `memcached` or `redis`, in which case it lives behind your application server. But it could be something like `varnish` in which case it lives in *front* of your load balancer. Or, it could be something like Cloudflare or Fast.ly which lives outside your network, in between the client and your load balancer.